# Redirect traffic from a OpenVPN server to an OpenVPN client running in the same device

Tags: openvpn

I have a raspberry box running an OpenVPN server that I'm using as a way to connect to use my Pihole installation when outside my home network. This is working without issues.

```
                     |          HOME NETWORK/Pihole  |
(Remote client)     --   (Open VPN Server )        ---         Internet
```

Separately I have a remote VPN service that I can connect to via an OpenVPN client from the Pi device. That I tested successfully as well.

```
                    |          HOME NETWORK/Pihole  |
                           (Open VPN Client )       -            VPN provider
```

I would like to be combine both services  such that the final installation would look like this

```
                 |          HOME NETWORK /Pihole           |
(Remote client) -- (Open VPN Server) -- (Open VPN Client) --- Remote VPN service
```

I have tried solutions like the one described in this similar question ([Wireguard server with active OpenVPN client](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516962/wireguard-server-with-active-openvpn-client)) with negative similar results: Once you activate the Open VPN client (tun1) the server (tun0) becomes unreachable.

Here's what the routing table looks like when both interfaces tun[01] are up

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.50.11.5 dev tun1
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.1.164 metric 303
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
10.50.11.1 via 10.50.11.5 dev tun1
10.50.11.5 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.50.11.6
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.50.11.5 dev tun1
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.164 metric 303
199.116.115.135 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

Here's the current output of my openvpn server when I try to connect.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn $ sudo more openvpn-status.log
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Sat Jun 29 23:30:41 2019
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
UNDEF,x.x.x.x:39159,860,442,Sat Jun 29 23:30:02 2019
```

This is what the error log looks like

```
Sat Jun 29 23:34:47 2019 x.x.x.x:28162 TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET]172.58.87.22:28162
Sat Jun 29 23:34:48 2019 x.x.x.x:28162 Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #1 / time = (1561869285) Sat Jun 29 23:34:45 2019 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more
info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings
Sat Jun 29 23:34:48 2019 x.x.x.x:28162 TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:28162
```

Apparently the client connection is getting corrupted?

I also tried the solution in [OpenVPN Client and Server on same machine - Server doesn't allow connections when client is connected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352841/openvpn-client-and-server-on-same-machine-server-doesnt-allow-connections-whe?rq=1) which I discovered after posting this question, to no avail. This would appear to be directly related to my issue but it's still not working.

Comment: I noticed while editing your post that you had a fragment: "Here's what the server log looks like", but I saw no further information. I removed the fragment, but consider *this* comment a friendly reminder to upload it, if it's different from the existing log information you have.

Comment: I didn't think your question was entirely clear. But let me try: Did you want to route traffic from your remote client to your remote VPN service? Are any of the OpenVPN configs pushing default routes to the clients (think the answer is yes for tun1 - connection to remote VPN service)? Do you have forwarding enabled between the two interfaces? And do you have NAT or masquerading enabled?

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o tun1 -j MASQUERADE
```

You will need this rule to route the outgoing traffic from the openvpn server (10.8.0.0/24) through your openvpn client connection (tun1)

To reach your openvpn server from outside your home network you have to use these rules from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352968/153415) answer:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.164 lookup 10           # Pi server
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table 10    # LAN router
```

Where *192.168.1.164* is your Pi-IP.
An alternative to only allow vpn traffic would be:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp --dport 1149 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 10
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 dev table 10
```

Comment: You are unlikely to get an answer posting a question in an answer. Better to post your question and then link it back to here.

Comment: @bu5hman Sorry for the confusion. I already solved both problems (routing outgoing vpnsrv traffic over vpnclient and making the server remotely available) So the bounty is obsolete and wasted. I hope the solution will help others with the same problem, upvotes appreciated ;)